# javascript variable and media screen

Tags: javascript, css, media, screen-orientation, var

I've just realized my plan won't work with an earlier [question](http://goo.gl/NviCs). So I need some advice.

I'm using javascript variable to get the width and height of all browsers.

```
var viewportwidth;
var viewportheight;
```

I and i'm applying these variables to my `<div id="wapper"></div>` like so...

```
$("#wrapper").css({
    "width": viewportwidth + 'px !important',
    "height": viewportheight + 'px !important'
});
```

But I'm also using @media screen for orientation changes on devices in my css.

Which I need to get these variables into it some how, But i'm not sure if it's best to either output the whole thing as javascript/jquery or if there's another way of adding a variable into the CSS

```
<style>

    #wrapper {
        width: viewportheight ;
        height: viewportwidth ;
    }

    /* Landscape */
    @media screen and (orientation:landscape) {

        #wrapper {
            width: viewportwidth !important;
            height: viewportheight !important;
        }

    }

    /* Portrait */
    @media screen and (orientation:portrait) {

        #wrapper {
            width: viewportheight !important;
            height: viewportwidth !important;
        }

    }

</style>
```

Any advice would be most awesome thanks!

Josh

---

UPDATE

Here's another method that I tried but still can't get it to work...

```
    $(".portrait").css({
        "width": viewportwidth + 'px !important',
        "height": viewportheight + 'px !important'
    });

    $(".landscape").css({
        "width": viewportheight + 'px !important',
        "height": viewportwidth + 'px !important'
    });

    detectOrientation();
        window.onorientationchange = detectOrientation;
        function detectOrientation(){
            if(typeof window.onorientationchange != 'undefined'){
                if ( orientation == 0 ) {

                    //Do Something In Portrait Mode
                    $("#wrapper").removeClass("landscape").addClass("portrait");

                }
                else if ( orientation == 90 ) {

                    //Do Something In Landscape Mode
                    $("#wrapper").removeClass("portrait").addClass("landscape");

                }
                else if ( orientation == -90 ) {

                    //Do Something In Landscape Mode
                    $("#wrapper").removeClass("portrait").addClass("landscape");

                }
                else if ( orientation == 180 ) {

                    //Do Something In Portrait Mode
                    $("#wrapper").removeClass("landscape").addClass("portrait");

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: If the wrapper needs to be full width/height, why aren't you just setting the css width and height to 100%?

Comment: I've got expanding menu's inside the wrapper, if it's a 100% it expands the wrapper, I need the wrapped to be fixed at the browser width every time. Plus i need the fixed height too.

Comment: html,body,#wrapper{width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;}

Comment: please see source and link [test project](http://motocomdigital.co.uk/development/html5/mobile-test/) - 100% width and height technically works, but on devices when you turn landscape, from portrait, it holds the portraits dimensions - vice versa (you will notice in the browser that i have max width of 1020px)

Comment: sorry, the orientation does work, but my problem is that the height is using the contents height and not the viewports height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel that you can solve this using css:

```
html,body,#wrapper{width:100%;overflow-x:hidden;}
```

and then you can position your expanding menus absolutely:

```
#menu{position:absolute,top:0}
```

with a margin on the content below the menus

```
#content{margin-top:50px}
```

of course it would help to see the html that you are using.
The height of the document should be that of the content normally. You should not have to set it with javascript.